# Map the types of a shapeless HList

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, hlist

I've been trying to map the types of an `HList` from scala's `shapeless` package without having access to their values.

The following succeeds in mapping the values of an HList

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.Poly._
import ops.hlist.Mapper
import ops.hlist.Mapper._

trait Person {
  type Value
  val v : Value
}

case class StringPerson extends Person {
  type Value = String
  val v = "I like strings"
}

case class IntPerson extends Person {
  type Value = Int 
  val v = 42
}

object what_is_going_on {

  object test_value_op {
    val stringPerson = StringPerson()
    val intPerson = IntPerson()

    trait lpvfun extends Poly1 {
      implicit def default[A <: Person] = at[A](_.v)
    } 

    object vfun extends lpvfun {}

    // Use these to generate compiler errors if the mapped type is not what we'd expect:

    type TestListType = StringPerson :: IntPerson :: HNil
    type TestListExpectedMappedType = String :: Int :: HNil

    // Input:
    val testList : TestListType = stringPerson :: intPerson :: HNil

    // Output:
    val mappedList : TestListExpectedMappedType = testList map vfun

    // Get the actual mapped type 
    type TestListActualMappedType = mappedList.type

    // This compiles......
    val mappedList1 : TestListActualMappedType = mappedList

    // .... but weirdly this line doesn't. That isn't the point of this question, but I'd be very grateful for an answer.
    //implicitly[TestListActualMappedType =:= TestListExpectedMappedType]
  }

}
```

Cool! Apart from not being able to use `implicitly[A =:= B]` for some reason, the values of an `HList` have been mapped and so have their types.

Now, suppose we don't have the `HList` value but we know its type. How can we map over its types?

I tried the following based on the definition of `map` [here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/3a02b7cb3f645077ad16caecbd07a74ff01813cf/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L397):

```
object test_type_op { 
  type TestListType = StringPerson :: IntPerson :: HNil
  type TestListExpectedMappedType = String :: Int :: HNil

  // Attempt 1 does not work, compiler cannot prove =:=
  type MappedType = Mapper[vfun.type, TestListType]#Out
  implicitly[MappedType =:= TestListExpectedMappedType]

  // Attempt 2 does not work, compiler cannot prove =:=
  class GetMapper {
    implicit val mapper : Mapper[vfun.type, TestListType]
    implicitly[mapper.Out =:= TestListExpectedMappedType]
  }

}
```

How does one get the type of a mapped `HList` without having access to its value? Is there a way of debugging why the compiler can't prove something? Thankyou for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `TestListActualMappedType` you've got the singleton type for `mappedList`, which isn't the same as the inferred type of `mappedList`. You can see exactly the same issue without involving Shapeless:

```
scala> val x = "foo"
x: String = foo

scala> implicitly[x.type =:= String]
<console>:13: error: Cannot prove that x.type =:= String.
       implicitly[x.type =:= String]
                 ^
```

You could ask for evidence that `x.type` is a subtype of `String` or you could use `shapeless.test.typed`, which would look like this in your case:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Mapper

trait Person {
  type Value
  val v : Value
}

case class StringPerson() extends Person {
  type Value = String
  val v = "I like strings"
}

case class IntPerson() extends Person {
  type Value = Int 
  val v = 42
}

trait lpvfun extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[A <: Person] = at[A](_.v)
} 

object vfun extends lpvfun {}

val stringPerson = StringPerson()
val intPerson = IntPerson()

val testList = stringPerson :: intPerson :: HNil
val mappedList = testList map vfun

shapeless.test.typed[String :: Int :: HNil](mappedList)
```

This doesn't really buy you much over explicitly specifying the type, though.

You can ask for evidence that the output type of a type class like `Mapper` is the type you expect for particular input types:

```
scala> val m = Mapper[vfun.type, StringPerson :: IntPerson :: HNil]
m: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[vfun.type,shapeless.::[StringPerson,shapeless.::[IntPerson,shapeless.HNil]]]{type Out = shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]} = shapeless.ops.hlist$Mapper$$anon$5@6f3598cd

scala> implicitly[m.Out =:= (String :: Int :: HNil)]
res1: =:=[m.Out,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]] = <function1>
```

This is more likely to be useful, but again it depends on what exactly you're trying to convince yourself of.

Comment: Thankyou - this really helps. In your second code block, what happens to `m` at compile time? Is it optimized out? Is there any way to get the type that `m.Out` would have without actually creating any values?